# simplification of powers.

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

I have the following fraction that I am trying to simplify. 
$$
\frac{1}{1-(1-x)^i} \bigg[\frac{(1-(1-x)^{i+1}) -(1-(1-x)^{2i})}{1-(1-x)}\bigg]
$$
I begin by pulling the denominator out of the fraction and multiplying it with the external factor, cancelling the numerator's 1s. 
$$
\frac{1}{x-(1-x)^{i+1}} \bigg[(-(1-x)^{i+1})-(1-x)^{2i})\bigg]
$$
I then pull $(1-x)^i$ out of the top. 
$$
\frac{-(1-x)^{i}}{x-(1-x)^{i+1}} \bigg[(1-x)+(1-x)^{i})\bigg]
$$
I am not sure how to proceed beyond this point. I believe the final answer should be:
$$
\frac{1 - (1-x)^{i+1}}{2-x}
$$

Comment: It's often easiest, in things like this, to look for a repeated expression, like $1-x$, and give it a new name, i.e., replace every occurrence of $1-x$ with $u$, so that your original becomes $$\frac{1}{1-u^i} \bigg[\frac{(1-u^{i+1}) -(1-u^{2i})}{1-u}\bigg]$$; when you're done simplifying, you replace $u$ with $1-x$ again.

Comment: Your very first step, multiplying the denominator of the second factor by that of the first, appears to me to be wrong. It should have produced a denominator of $x - x(1-x)^i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify it as: $$\frac{1}{1-(1-x)^i}[\frac{(1-x)^{2i}-(1-x)^{i+1}}{x}]$$ $$=\frac{(1-x)^i}{1-(1-x)^i}[\frac{(1-x)^i-(1-x)}{x}]$$

There is a **mistake** in your second step where $x[1-(1-x)^{i}]$ should be $x-x(1-x)^{i}$ and not $x-(1-x)^{i+1}$.